# Get 'less' to display filename

Tags: arch-linux, grep, less

Something that seemed quite useful to me when looking for a certain var in a bunch of config files:

`less * | grep some_var`

So this returns the value of `some_var` without manually looking through all config files. Nice! But what if I didn't only want to know the value of `some_var` and wanted to change it? What file is it in? How do I get the `less` command (or `grep`, or another command) to display the var and what file it was found in?

I searched the man-page, but couldn't find any suitable option...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why pipe `less` into anything? That turns it into `cat`. The obvious answer is

```
grep some_var * | less
```

You'll get output of the form

```
filename:this line contains some_var somewhere
```

If you pass the option `-n` to `grep`, you also get line numbers:

```
filename:42:this line contains some_var somewhere
```

Many editors have some form of file search built in, with the search results appearing in a window where you can select a line to open the corresponding file at the corresponding location. In Emacs, run [`M-x grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Grep-Searching.html) or one of its variants. In Vim, run [`:grep`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/quickfix.html#%3agrep) or one of its variants.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I couldn't think the other way round, I'm always using `grep` in some other situation as a kind of 'helper command', not realizing I could use it on its own just as well. Extra points for the `-n` option, quite handy.

Answer (score 6):

`less` isn't really meant for doing what you're trying to do; it's for displaying long text files in a paginated format.

`grep` allows for a file or list of files to be passed as a command line argument, so you can simply do

```
grep -H some_var *
```

which will give you output that looks like this because the `-H` option prefixes the name to the result:

```
filename: some_var blah blah
```

If you still want to pipe it into `less` so that you can scroll through it, you're able to do that.

```
grep -H some_var * | less
```

---

Another recommendation for grepping through numerous files is `ack` or `ack-grep` as it's known on Debian systems. It's designed for searching source trees fairly quickly by ignoring binary files and also requires less keystrokes to do similar searches.

Comment: Equally right, good point about the purpose of `less` being to display long text files.

Comment: note, if glob pattern (`*` in this case) matches only 1 file, grep will not display a file name, so you have to force it: `grep -H`

Comment: @sendmoreinfo: Thanks, good point. Added that in.